# Sonata Admin local translation strategy for a list column

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is there an easy way to adjust a local translation strategy for a field added to a `listMapper`? So the column header will be shown exactly how it's been written in a `label` attribute without any gaps.

<kbd>BusinessUserAdmin.php</kbd>

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('company', null, [
            'label' => 'Company'
        ])
}
```

This is how it looks like now:

<kbd>'label' => 'Company'</kbd>      
<kbd>'label' => 'COmpany'</kbd>      
<kbd>'label' => 'COMPANY'</kbd>

[image: Company]     [image: COmpany]       [image: COMPANY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your admin class as service and tag it with : `sonata.admin`, there is additional option `label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore”`

You can find more info here :

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html

Comment: Yeap, I know that one can change translation strategy for the whole admin. Do you know if it's possible to override strategy for one particular field?

Comment: @camel_case not sure if that is possible, but you can use tags for labels and then translate it on your own

Comment: looks like it's the only credible answer by now